# Adding multiple people to another table in one form

Tags: forms, record

I have a table holding peoples details (id, name, age, telephone) and I want to be able to select a set amount of these people in a list using a radio button and add these to an appointment table.

So in one click it will add each person to the appointments table all having an ID relating them to the appointment.

Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction as to how I would achieve this.

Thanks

Matthew

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: Ive tried using a putting a table row in a while loop and the table rows appear and a radio button in column 1 on each row. When I name the radio button then I can only select on.

Comment: I am trying to repeat the row so I can insert multiple rows